# Error when trying to add hibernate to spring project

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I'm trying to add hibernate to my spring project for database persistence, I've downloaded hibernate 4.1.6 the latest stable version and I'm using spring 3.1.

However when I try and run my project I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 
'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError:   
Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file  
javax/validation/Validation
```

The external jars I've added to my project so far are:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar
hibernte-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.6.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
```

My pom.xml contains the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks for your help, any alterations that should be made to my question please let me know.

Daniel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261899/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-with-contextconfigurationclasses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863235/junit-testcase-passes-with-eclipse-but-fails-with-maven-build Seems like a duplicate, it has to do with jee dependencies

Comment: another strange thing that you reference hibernate entity manager(which references hibernate) and use separate jar files. Also you have both jee dependency and jpa 2 implementation jar file in your configuration I suppose that it can be the source of different conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with `javaee-api` dependency in the Maven repository, as a solution you can switch to alternative ones

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
       <artifactId>geronimo-ejb_3.1_spec</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
       <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Credits: This solution is discussed [here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/trouble_with_crippled_java_ee).

See also [Failed to load ApplicationContext with @ContextConfiguration(classes={ ... })](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261899/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-with-contextconfigurationclasses) and [JUnit testcase passes with eclipse but fails with maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863235/junit-testcase-passes-with-eclipse-but-fails-with-maven-build)

**update** It's not understood why you have downloaded separate hibernate jar files(including JPA 2.0 implementation) if you have Hibernate entity manager and Java EE dependencies in your pom.xml

Comment: Oh its probably down to following a variety of set up tutorials, I'll slim it down to remove duplicates later, thank you though your solution worked!